# What data type should I use on AWS Glue's DynamicFrame.apply_mapping for a list of strings field?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

When using AWS Glue's [DynamicFrame.apply_mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-apply_mapping), the documentation doesn't specify how I should encode the field's type. It shows some examples for basic types, such as strings and dates. But how should I encode a "list of strings"? I tried `"string[]"` but that throws an exception.